# How does Qt 5.6 know the proper QObject address to post a keyboard event?

Tags: c++11, qt5, embedded-linux

I'm currently making a software for an embedded system and we're using Qt 5.6.

We have some generic physical buttons that I get the state of via a message over a serial port and this part is working as expected.

I just need to simulate a keyboard event (Tab, Backtab) when I get the respective serial message.

My window creation system is a little confusing, but everything works fine when I plug in a physical keyboard and move focus around the screen using the Tab or Backtab buttons.

My problem starts when I try to post a manual keyboard event using the most common suggestion on the internet. I just can't seem to get the event to land correctly on the window/widget the user is trying to interact with.

```
QKeyEvent* keyEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Backtab, Qt::NoModifier, QString(), false);
QObject* obj = QApplication::focusWidget();
QApplication::postEvent(obj, keyEvent);
```

I tried using `QApplication::activePopupWidget()`, `QApplication::activeModalWidget()`, `QApplication::activeWindow()`, `QApplication::focusWidget()` and `QApplication::focusWindow()` but none of these functions gives me the correct window/widget in the same way as simply pressing Tab on a real keyboard. They work sometimes, but there is always a condition where they fail.

For example, sometimes I open a new window and the manual Tab event continues to interact with the previous window's widgets. I then press Tab on the real keyboard and the focus is correctly moved to the new window and now manual Tab starts working in the correct window.

So my question is, what is the way Qt is using to detect the correct window/widget when it receives a real keyboard event? Does it use any other functions other than one of these, or is there some test I should do combining some of these functions?

Edit: My best solution so far, was to use `QApplication::focusWidget()` since I need to pass the event to ComboBoxes and other widgets that aren't windows. But there was still an issue that when I clicked on a button to open a new window or a combobox (drop list), the `QApplication::focusWidget()` was still giving me the pointer to the previous screen and wasn't moving the focus properly. So I added a call to `QWidget::setFocus()` after creating a new window to force the focus to move manually. I still think that I shouldn't need to make this call, since it isn't needed to make a real keyboard work, so if anyone has an answer I'd still appreciate.

Comment: Rather than trying to simulate Tab press, it might be more straightforward to just pass the focus to the right widget. See `QWidget::nextInFocusChain` and `QWidget::previousInFocusChain()`; you would call those on `QApplication::activeWindow()`

Comment: I also use it for other keys (space for selection and F1-F6 for custom functions). All this behavior already works for Qt key press events, if everything fails i will rework to try your suggestion, but it shouldn't be this hard to use something already built in in Qt,